# How do I get my dates in standard unambiguous formats if they can't be recognized due to their ambiguous format?

Tags: r

I want to split up a Timestamp from Excel into year and julian day.  I know, duplicate question, but combining everything I have found from other questions is not helping me.

The timestamp is formatted `1/13/2011 13:55` .  So, I wanted to tell R to recognize this as a time variable.  I have hours and minutes so I tried as.POSIXct and as.POSIXlt.  These didn't work.  I tried adding `strptime`  --

```
as.POSIXct(strptime(df$TIMESTAMP, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M%S"))
```

I just got NAs.

Once I got R to recognize it as a date, I was going to use lubridate like `day(df$Date)`.

Comment: No function will work if you specify the format incorrectly. What calendar are you using that has 13 months? ;)

Comment: Do you really have the month first? Do you mean `strptime(df$TIMESTAMP, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")`??

Comment: I know I should feel terrible, but my laughter is uncontrollable -- the really delirious kind.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as though you have month and day reversed

```
 1/13/2011 13:55
```

with

```
"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M%S"
```

corresponds to the 1st day of the 13th month, which is probably why you're getting NAs. This seems to work for me:

```
a <- "01/13/2011 13:55"

t <- strptime(a, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
t
"2011-01-13 13:55:00"
```

Comment: Absolutely not, just saw that. I'd be happy to take down my answer, if you think that is the correct etiquette though.

Comment: Behavior? I answered a question and tried to help. Did not see the comments. I came up with my answer independently, but I do see that the comments were made before I answered.